# XML Post to iSeries Web Service

Tags: xml-parsing

I have created a web service on the iSeries using IBM Web Administration.  I also have a RPGILE program that will be triggered during a POST request.

The Post Request passes a XML string.  The RPGILE program is triggered but the passed parm(xml String) is empty or is not being passed.

The error that I am receiving is RNX0351 .. The XML parser detected error code 300. --> **300   The parser reached the end of the document before the document was complete.**

The xml that should be passed is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<CLM transId="123abcdef">
   <ABC>
       <DEF>
           <123>
               <XYZ number="123456" Res1="WhoCares" Res2="222" Res3="" />
           </123>
       </DEF>
   </ABC>
</CLM>
```

Thanks 
Don S.

Comment: Seeing the other relevant code would be helpful

Comment: As this is my first attempt at working with web services and I am unsure what relevant code you would be looking for?    I have a RPGILE program on the iSeries that should be called when the services receives a POST command.    Currently I am trying to use a GOANYWHERE project to test the service.    The service was created using the iSeries Web Service. wizard.

Answer (score 0):

XML Element names must start with a letter or underscore according to https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_elements.asp.

So your element `<123>` is not valid which may be causing the error.

Comment: My mistake.  <123> </123> was just used for an example.  I think what I need to do is find someone that know the IBM web Administration for i and the process of deploying  a Web Services.  Thanks